# mysql selecting data from a table

Tags: mysql

I have an Users Table with a staff column and a remove column.

I don't want to show Users that have the remove column with the value of 1

```
SELECT *
            FROM Users
            WHERE
            Users.staff = 1
            AND Users.remove != 1
```

I don't get an error but my code doesn't work.

this is the schema

```
    CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `userId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fullName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastName` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `city` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zipCode` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cellPhone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthDate` date NOT NULL,
  `creditCard` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `subscriptionStarted` date NOT NULL,
  `subscriptionEnded` date NOT NULL,
  `basicPlan` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `standardPlan` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `premiumPlan` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remove` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `systemAdmin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edited` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "doesn't work". What is the table structure? What data is in the table? What should the result set be? What is the actual result set.

Comment: "doesn't work"? No rows returned? That's not "not work". A result set with no rows is a perfectly VALID result. "not work" is the query failed outright with a syntax or other error.

Comment: the values of my remove the value is null but is have change the value null to zero my query works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both work for me Boss.

```
create table users
(   staff int not null,
    remove int not null
);

insert users (staff,remove) values (1,0);
insert users (staff,remove) values (1,1);
insert users (staff,remove) values (2,0);
insert users (staff,remove) values (2,1);


SELECT *
            FROM Users
            WHERE
            Users.staff = 1
            AND Users.remove != 1

SELECT *
            FROM Users
            WHERE
            Users.staff = 1
            AND Users.remove <> 1
```

**Edit due to nullability:**

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE staff=1
and remove <> 1 or remove is null

SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE staff=1
and remove is not null
```